# ffmpeg - Output file does not contain any stream

Tags: ffmpeg, debian

When I try to take Screenshots from an AVI file I get the above message with an empty jpg/png file. But Screenshots from MP4 files works with any problems.

My OS is Debian.

MP4 Command:

```
ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i test.mp4 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 test.jpg
```

AVI Command:

```
ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i test.avi -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 test.jpg
```

Comment: Interesting. I would expect both to fail. What are the codex and pix_fmt used by your test videos?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `-f image2` instead of `-f rawvideo`. This tells ffmpeg to write an image, rather than an uncompressed video stream. An uncompressed video stream obviously cannot be saved in a still image file.

Also, since you're saving to JPEG, you should use `-vcodec copy` to avoid applying lossy JPEG compression unnecessarily.

Comment: You can't just take an encoded video frame and save it as a JPEG. A change of codec is required.